# Segmentation fault printf

Tags: slam

When I build rgb lsd_slam

I search about segmentation fault, and I know something about it. But when I debug by stepping through each line, I get the result following:

```
for (float* pt = data.imageRGB[0]; pt < maxPtRGB; pt++) {
    *pt = *rgbImage;    
    printf("3!\n");
    rgbImage++;
}

for(float* pt = data.imageRGB[0]; pt < maxPtRGB; pt++) {
    *pt = *rgbImage;
    rgbImage++;
}
```

If you see the two above, the first run without the problem, and the second will show the segmentation fault. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What is your question? You've told us something you know; you haven't told us what you *don't* know and are here to determine.

Comment: If it's just a question of "why can a standard-library function call make a difference?" -- accessing beyond allocated memory leads to undefined behavior in C, so the language is perfectly within specification to do anything, including crashing only conditionally. I'm half wondering if you might have overwritten the stack pointer, such that an attempt to return could fail, but that's ill-informed speculation.

Comment: Yes, my question is why they have different results while only different with printf, this should have no effect on the memory of the other variables.

Comment: Any function call consumes content on the stack. If you corrupted the stack pointer through an out-of-bounds write, it overwrites... well, whatever's after that position.

Comment: (err, not so much "consumes content on the stack" as "uses working space on the stack", but the principle applies)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's a long way for me to understand computer.